# Calculating object differences and the Actions Required to reconcile

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

Given I have a type we'll call `Person` defined as

```
// psuedo code
Person {
    Name: string;
    Age: int;
    Friends: Person[];
    Career: Career // black box and assume that Career 
                   // is a type with a few arbitrary properties
}
```

Given I have two instances of the `Person` type, we will call `p1 and p2`

p1 is filled up with information like `Name = "jim"` and  `Age = 16` and `p1.Friends = [3 other Person references]`

and p2 is filled up with different information like `Name = "bill"` and `Age = 21` and `p2.Friends = [5 other Person references]`

Now if I wanted to transform p1 into p2 there are a series of CRUD actions  could take like:

```
p1.UpdateName("bill")
p1.UpdateAge(21)
p1.DeleteFriend(friends[i]) //For each of the current friends in p1 that are not in p2
p1.CreateFriend(newFriends[j]) //For each of the friends in p2 that are not in p1
```

And now the data in p1 is equal to the data in p2.

It is easy enough to take two objects of a specific known type, calculate the difference between them and produce a set of distinct actions that will transform one object into the other, I would like the generalize this workflow in a way that is designed to allow us to easily diff many different types of object and produce a common set of actions that can transform any instance of a particular type to any other instance of the same type.

My question is:

Is there an existing solution (library or common design) that solves what I am attempting to do?
 Will it account for deeply nested objects? Like in the example I have the career property in the Person type and If there were differences there, I would need to calculate actions for that as well.

I don't want to try and reinvent the wheel on this if it's been done better, I just don't know what to search for in google when it comes to figuring out this design.

If it helps at all the actual target language for this is C#.

Comment: What advantage do you see in figuring out the steps to transform one instance into another when you can simply force the whole thing into a known-correct state?  (Also, design patterns aren't Tinkertoys you pull out of a bucket to assemble software.  Write the code that does the work and, if you must, use patterns to describe what you did.)

Comment: @Blrfl The action list would be stored to create a history and allow us to reproduce the steps taken to get the the current value. Granted in my example above this seems useless but for what I am trying to apply it to, this comes in handy. We will be given two state blobs and I will need to figure out the primitive operations to get from state1 to state2. Also design pattern is probably not the correct term I updated it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to determine is called an object tree minimal delta. Googling around for those terms yielded [this article](https://danielwertheim.se/how-to-build-a-simple-object-graph-delta-comparer-in-csharp-using-structurizer/) which should get you going in the right direction.